# Excel formula help for calculating values from another sheet if conditions are met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to formulate this in excel but not sure where to start so here is the “pseudo” code:

Sheet 1 cell b2 = if cell a2 on sheet 2 is equal to “apple” and cell b2 on sheet 2 is equal to “fresh” then return the total of all values in sheet 2 column c.

On sheet 1 column a, I have a list of of 10 fruits.

On sheet 2 column a, I have the same list of 10 fruits but with many repeating (lets say 200 rows)

On sheet 2 column b, I have the state of the fruit - “fresh” and “expired”

On sheet 2 column c,I have the price of each fruit (with variations in the price for the same fruit)

On sheet 1 column b, My aim is to calculate the total price of only the corresponding “fresh” fruit on sheet 2.

So if sheet 1, cell a2 is apple, what formula could i use in sheet 1 cell b2 to work out the total amount of the fresh apples on sheet 2?

(Sorry question is a bit long but i tried to give as much detail as i could)

I tried vlookup but i only know the basics.  I also tried IF and COUNTIF but I dont know how to use these functions properly. Novice excel user.

Comment: Check out sumif() or sumifs() - Excel has explanations to get you started.

Comment: As a confidence boost (start), u may try to pt both table on the same sheet 1st n test the formula.. | ref : https://exceljet.net/functions/sumif-function